# AWS CodePipeline Build error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I created an AWS CodePipeline pipeline to pull from Github, build with Jenkins, and deploy to an ElasticBeanstalk project. I can deploy the war to beanStack directly and validate.

When i try to do the same from CodePipeLine i see the below error in AWS CodePipeline Polling Log of Jenkins -

> ERROR: Failed to record SCM polling for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@ae44565e6[AppPortal]
>   com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.model.ActionTypeNotFoundException: ActionType (Category: 'Build', Owner: 'Custom', Provider: 'MPiplelineProvider', Version: '1') is not available (Service: AWSCodePipeline; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ActionTypeNotFoundException; Request ID: e35456561d-999f-56e7-3rgf-75985675533b3)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1401)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:945)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:723)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:475)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:437)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:386)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.doInvoke(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:2078)

I have set the SCM poll to * * * * * for testing purpose.

Post-build Actions - AWS CodePipeline publisher - Location - target/AppPortal

I installed only AWS Codepipeline pulgin in jenkins.

Can you let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register the Jenkins custom action type in CodePipeline, in the same region you're polling?

Check your Jenkins job configuration for:

- AWS Region
- Category
- Provider
- Version

From your error message:

```
ActionType (Category: 'Build', Owner: 'Custom', Provider: 'MPiplelineProvider', Version: '1')
```

Then use the AWS CLI to list your custom action types, in that region, and make sure the Category, Provider, and Version match:

```
aws codepipeline list-action-types --action-owner-filter Custom --region us-west-2
```

If you created the Jenkins action type through the AWS Console, it should have these values:

```
ActionType (Category: 'Build', Owner: 'Custom', Provider: 'Jenkins', Version: '1')
```

If that's the case, updating your Jenkins job Provider from *MPiplelineProvider* to *Jenkins* should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see the error after changing the location and Provider name to Jenkins. But i still can't get the build working.   I checked the pipeline logs and see this messages. '[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] No jobs found.' I checked the CodePipeline is using the exact same ProjectName and ActionType as whatever Jenkins server is polling for

Comment: I restarted jenkins instance and the codepipeline build and deploys now.Not sure why a restart had anything to do with it but worked for me. As its restarted, the public DNS for jenkins changed and i can't navigate to new jenkin page from codepipeline. It still has reference to old jenkins url, how can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

In our scenario:
  Trigger: moving the Jenkins master (ec2) behind a Load Balancer.

Symptom: we started getting the same error (as above) after updating all security group setting so that load balancer does not get in the way.

Resolution:

On the Jenkins (ec2) box, we deleted the "project" and re-creating it with the exact same setting (including name) as before. This allowed Jenkins to reconnect with Code Pipeline and job started working again.

Here is the codepipeline stage action settings:

{
                        "inputArtifacts": [], 
                        "name": "foobar-test", 
                        "region": "us-west-2", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Test", 
                            "owner": "Custom", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "foobar-provider"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "foobar-api-qa-aws_trigger"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1